# Why is aspnet preventing browser page caching when a csrf token is present?

Tags: asp.net-core, security, csrf

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.antiforgery.iantiforgery.getandstoretokens?view=aspnetcore-5.0), generating a csrf token with asp.net will also prevent the response to be cached by the browser.

> Generates an AntiforgeryTokenSet for this request and stores the cookie token in the response. This operation also sets the "Cache-control" and "Pragma" headers to "no-cache" and the "X-Frame-Options" header to "SAMEORIGIN".

I initially assumed that this decision was made to prevent users from submitting a "stale" request token by using the browser "back" button. I later noticed that this might not be the reason, since :

- asp.net keeps the same cookie token for the whole session.
- asp.net allows the same request token to be submitted many times as long as the cookie token doesn't change.

So, from my current understanding, using the browser back button and submit a cached html page should not be a problem ?

What is then the justification for disabling browser page caching when it contains a csrf token ? Is this a security best practice ?

**EDIT**

As @serpent5 rightfully pointed out, the header `Cache-Control: no-store` ensures that a public cache won't cache the response and serve it to a different user. To clarify, I am more specifically interested in knowing if enabling browser caching (`Cache-Control: private`) would have a negative impact on security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already did a good job in describing the antiforgery protection setup in `ASP.NET`.
In addition, I included some parts of the official documentation here below.

The main thing to remember is that a set of tokens get generated which go into a session cookie and hidden form tag, and that only the presence of that exact combination will pass the security check.
When the session expires, new tokens get generated.

Now the reason why private caching cannot be allowed has to do with expiration timing.

In case the web page would have a cache duration that would exceed the expiration of the anti-XSRF session, the user would end up with the previous/old token coming from the cache, since that one is being reused.
When submitting that web page, the server side security check will fail in case a new session would have been started (until the page cache invalidates).

Since anti-XSRF cookies are session cookies, they get deleted when closing the web browser. On a subsequent request a new session will be started and new tokens will be generated. The presence of the corresponding still valid cached web page would immediately result in the above security check fail situation.

---

Some quotes from the documentation at [XSRF/CSRF Prevention in ASP.NET MVC and Web Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages)

> The ASP.NET Web Stack Runtime uses a variant of the synchronizer token
> pattern to defend against XSRF attacks.  The general form of the
> synchronizer token pattern is that two anti-XSRF tokens are submitted
> to the server with each HTTP POST (In addition to the authentication
> token): **one token as a cookie, and the other as a form value**.

> In per-session token implementation after initial generation of token,
> the value is stored in the session and is used for each subsequent
> request **until the session expires**.

> When the tokens are submitted, the server will allow the request to
> proceed **only if both tokens pass a comparison check**.

> If **a new anti-XSRF token** was generated in step (1), **a new session
> token** will be created to contain it and will be added to **the outbound
> HTTP cookies collection**. The field token from step (2) will be wrapped
> in an **`<input type="hidden" />` element**.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! I think I understand why the check would fail if the web browser cache lifetime exceeds the session. 
However, I'm still not sure to understand when this situation would happen with `Cache-Control: private`. I noticed that browsers don't seem to reuse a `private` response except when navigating back/forward (I may be wrong here ?).  RFC 7234 indeed seems to allow reusing this response. Is asp.net simply being extra cautious by strictly following RFC 7234 or am I missing real scenarios where this would cause problems with web browsers ?

Comment: Reusing the tokens is fine, as long as no new session has started. When navigating backwards in an active session, the tokens don’t change as it is still the same session. When a web page requested today would have a 2 days cache duration, the hidden form field token will be reused tomorrow, and by then a new session will have been started with new token expectations.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with _”browsers don’t seem to reuse a private response”_; when the caching headers have been set up appropriately (with an expires or max age) the cached data will be taken into account.

Comment: I meant that with `Cache-Control: private` alone (no max-age/expires), browsers don't seem to ever display cached responses, except when using the browser history (I could not find sources to confirm this). 
The `Cache-Control: no-store` added by aspnet causes some issues with some of our users because the state of form field values is lost when they go back in their browser's history (this forces the browser to reload the page). So we're thinking of instead using `Cache-Control: private` (+ clearing all max-age/expires headers) but we are not sure if this would introduce bugs/security flaws.

Comment: I've accepted your answer since it answers the original question. Thanks again for your help !

Comment: @SimonV. My situation seems exactly the same as you described in your comment - my team has found that `Cache-Control: private` tends to keep cached responses and form fields when navigating backward, and not any other time, which is ideal for our users. While it's concerning that this case seems to be a gray area, we want to continue using `Cache-Control: private`. Did you end up using `Cache-Control: private` and disregarding Core's convention to apply `no-store`, or did you find bugs/security flaws with that approach? Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewMessier Yes, we went for `private` instead of `no-store`. We haven't had any issues so far, but I wouldn't go as far as saying that this approach is battle-tested.